# How to start mysql automatically if that stop for any reason?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have a digitalocean ubuntu vps for development use only, But sometimes the mysql server stop working. 
As per my investigation I don't have enough memory to handle few laravel installation. As I use the server only for development purpose so I don't want to upgrage the server. So for now I have to start the mysql when that stop working.

Is there anyway that will start mysql automatically once that stop working?

Answer (score 5):

The tool that is generally used for this purpose is [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Digital Ocean has a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit) about it, which also includes an example on how to keep MySQL running. The short synopsis is:

1. Install monit

   ```
   sudo apt-get install monit
   ```
2. Edit the configuration file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/monit/monitrc
   ```

   and include the following in it:

   ```
   check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
       start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
       stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
   ```
3. Reload the new configuration:

   ```
   monit reload
   ```

I strongly suggest you look at the MySQL error log to understand why it is stopping (it should not do this in normal operation). It would be a good idea to also run [mysqlrepair](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/mysqlrepair.1.html) to check the status of all tables as you might have some serious DB corruption.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql stops working you need to investigate why. There is no reason for it to behave this way. Make sure that you have enough memory and that you allocate swap.